# how to convert hex string to ObjectId in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I a list of ObjectId's that I'm iterating over to the find values in a dict where the keys are ObjectId's.

```
email_count = 0
# user_id_list is a list of ObjectId's
for user_id in user_id_list:
    # UuserIdemailCountD is a dict where they keys are objectIds
    email_count +=  UuserIdemailCountD[user_id]
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
email_count +=  UuserIdemailCountD[user_id]
KeyError: ObjectId('54a9c84ebf2e4e5b258b5412')
```

When i iterate over `user_id_list` and just print the ids, I get a plain string like this `54a9c84ebf2e4e5b258b5412`.

Is the answer to convert the string to ObjectId's?  If so, how?

Comment: try this:  email_count+=UuserIdemailCountD.get(user_id, 0)  so if user_id doesn't exist it will return 0 which doesn't affect the result......the value in the UuserIdemailCountD dict are all numerical values right?

Comment: that worked.  buy why?

Comment: and did you get correct `email_count` or just a zero?

Answer (score 41):

Import ObjectId:

```
from bson import ObjectId
```

From ObjectId to string:

```
oid = ObjectId()
oid_str = str(oid)
# oid_str is now '555fc7956cda204928c9dbab'
```

From string to ObjectId:

```
oid_str = '555fc7956cda204928c9dbab'
oid2 = ObjectId(oid_str)
print(repr(oid2))
# ObjectId('555fc7956cda204928c9dbab')
```

Comment: How would one concatenate oid2 in order to do a query like this...
    q = "{_id: { $in: [" + ids + "] } }"