# Python List without the ObjectId to query in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to make a query in Mongo through the Python Shell

```
query2 = (
  {
    "itemId":{"$in": List},
  "startDate" : {"$gt": start_date} 
  },
  {"a":1, 'b':1, 'startDate':1}
)
```

List has this format

```
[u'abcd1',
 u'abcd2',
 u'abcd3']
```

Pb: It returns 0

I guess it's because in my Mongo DB the itemId has this format :

```
ObjectId("abcd1")
```

Tried this

```
portsList = map(lambda x: "ObjectId('" +  x +"')", portsList)
```

But it won't work

Comment: It's not a string. There is actually an [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) function to import which returns the correct type.

Comment: can you be more specific? I really am a beginner in Python and dont find anything on this function on google

Comment: [Read the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407166/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-objectid-in-python). You import the function and then use that in your lambda expression instead of concatenating as a "string".